# Should JasperReports questions that only interact with the graphical Interface be migrated to SU?

Tags: discussion, migration

Today I came across this question: [subreport loop when horizontal print order with multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749701/subreport-loop-when-horizontal-print-order-with-multiple-columns) and I have happened to meet many more of the same in the past. The thing with them is that they contain no code and won't ever do so. I also have only very seldom seen people request part of the xml-source in the comments in order to clarify questions like this.

As far as I understood the difference between SO and SU the questions should be migrated to SU as they only care about the interaction of a user with that program and do not actually include programming.

On the other hand, JR is a tool that is used primary by programmers and that usually involves knowing at least a bit of SQL in order to create the dataset one wants to have a report of. JR Reports are also often included in programs that need to be written by the same programmer, so its definitely a "programmer tool".

## Background

The Dataformat of Jasper Reports is a complex XML and is usually not interacted with by the developer. While many good JR Developers do know it and can read it, next to nobody is going to write that by hand. Instead the Reports are created by a graphical program (e.G. iReport).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The thing with them is that they contain no code and won't ever do so

So? That doesn't automatically make such questions off-topic.

I invite you to look at the list of [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topc):

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

And, as you say:

> JR is a tool that is used primary by programmers

That it's graphical in nature doesn't make it off-topic.

Some questions could find a home on several different sites. That doesn't mean they should get migrated away from a site they conceptually belong on just because there might be another site that fits better, conceptually.

If that was not the case, we should migrate all SQL questions to the DBA stack exchange.